# Sketch set of complex numbers $z$ such that $\Re\left(\frac{z-2}{z-2i}\right) = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers

I have this problem on my maths exam and I got stuck.

> Sketch all of numbers that satisfy $\Re\left(\frac{z-2}{z-2i}\right) = 0$.

What I did:

$$\frac{z-2}{z-2i} = \frac{(x-2) + iy}{x + i(y-2)}\\
    \frac{(x-2) + iy}{x + i(y-2)} × \frac{x - i(y-2)}{x - i(y-2)}\\
    \cdots$$
Finally getting this
$$\Re\left(\frac{z-2}{z-2i}\right) = 0 \implies x(x-2) + y(y-2) = 0$$

Idk what to do next.

**EDIT:** Thanks for all the answers. I got it figured out. I just had to "complete the square" to get an equation of the circle and after was just matter of plotting it.

Comment: if you complete the square, for $x$ and for $y$ you get a circle

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Note that this is related to [Thales's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem)

Comment: Also your last eqn is eqn of circle with diametric end points $(0,0)$ and $(2,2)$

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use that $Re\left(\frac{z-2}{z-2i}\right) = 0\iff \frac{z-2}{z-2i}$ is purely imaginary, therefore

$$\frac{z-2}{z-2i}=-\frac{\bar z-2}{\bar z+2i}
\iff z\bar z+2iz-2\bar z-4i=-z\bar z+2z+2i\bar z-4i
\\\iff (z+\bar z)-i(z+z\bar)=z\bar z 
\iff 2Re(z)+2Im(z)=|z|^2
\\\iff 2x+2y=x^2+y^2\iff x^2-2x+y^2-2y=0\iff (x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=2$$

Comment: There must be an error somewhere, your final equation is not correct.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks I check!

Comment: Centre is 1,1 so ...

Comment: @MartinR now it should be fine, anyway the main idea to use the first fact does not change, thanks!

Comment: @KingTut now it should be fine, anyway the main idea to use the first fact does not change, thanks!

Comment: Obviously I never deny the truth. Like it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Möbius transform, hence the image as well as pre-image of a line-or-circle is a line-or-circle (in the extended complex plane, i.e., with a point at infinity added). Here, we are looking for the pre-image of the imaginary axis (i.e., a line), so it must be a line or a circle.

Let's see if we can guess enough points to determine the line or circle:

- $z=2$ maps to $0$, so is on our curve.
- $z=0$ maps to $\frac{-2}{-2i}=-i$, so is on our curve.
- If $z=2i$ makes the denominator zero, hence maps to $\infty$ (which is a point on every line in the extended plane), so $2i$ is on our curve. (To be precise, whether or not the point $2i$ belongs to the answer curve, may depend on your local customs, see below)

As these three points are not collinear, we are looking for a circle, not for a line.
It must be the circle passing through $0$, $2$, and $2i$. Depending on whether or not you routinely work with the extended complex numbers, you may have to remove the single point $2i$ from this circle and indicate that gap accordingly in your sketch.

Answer (score 0):

Argument of the given quotient is 90 or 270 degeee since it's real part is zero. So angle between segment joining $z$ and $2$ and $z$ and $2i$ is either 90 or 270. This implies locus is a circle with diametric end points $2$ and $2i$.

But $z$ cannot be $2i$ since then quotient is I'll defined.

Answer (score 0):

1) Decompose the number $z$ in real ane imaginary part:
$$z = a + bi$$,
your equation will be then:

$$\mathrm{Re}\Bigl(\frac{a+ib - 2}{a+ib-2i}\Bigr) = 0$$

2)  be aware that the denominator should be not zero: your solution cannot be $a+ib -2i = 0$ which implies that $(a=0, b=2)$ could not be a solution of our equation

3) now you could rename your fraction as

$$\frac{a+ib - 2}{a+ib-2i} = c + di$$

and since you want the real part $c$ to be 0, then you can quickly write:

$$\frac{a+ib - 2}{a+ib-2i} = di$$

which implies

$$a+ib - 2 = di(a+ib-2i)$$

which implies

$$a+ib - 2 -dai +db - 2d = 0.$$

4) Solve the equation using a system, where you ensure both real part and imaginary part to be equal to zero

$$b-da = 0$$ and

$$a - 2  +db - 2d = 0.$$.
First equation brings you to say $d = \frac{b}{a}$. We substitute to the second equation, and we get

$$a - 2  +\frac{b}{a} b - 2\frac{b}{a} = 0.$$.

thus, $a^2 - 2a + b^2 - 2b = 0 $ provided both $a\neq 0$ and not $(a=0, b=2)$, is the space of your solution .